# In-lining a pass by reference call in PHP

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, php-7

I have a question regarding the pass-by-reference in PHP. I've searched online but couldn't see anything specific to this issue. The following function removes the key from the array and returns it's value updating the array:

```
function array_fetch($k, array &$a){
    if(isset($a[$k]) || array_key_exists($k, $a)){
        $v = $a[$k];
        unset($a[$k]);
        return $v;
    }

    return null;
}
```

I'm using the code as followed:

```
function foo(){
  return ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}

$a = foo();
echo array_fetch(1, $a);
print_r($a);
```

> b
>   Array ( [0] => a [2] => c )

So it works like a charm and now I want to make the code a little shorter:

```
echo array_fetch(1, $a = foo());
print_r($a);
```

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in ...
>   b
>   Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c )

Am I wrong to assume that I give a variable as reference? Apparently so, cause the array is unchanged as well but I don't understand *why* this happens. Even if I enclose the expression with `()` it doesn't help.

**Update:**

A viable work-around is to use a wrapper function like so:

```
function &ref($var){
  return $var;
}

echo array_fetch(1, $a = &ref(['a', 'b', 'c']));
print_r($a);
```

> b
>   Array ( [0] => a [2] => c )

Comment: The workaround for this issue is to first make the assignment and then use the variable in the function call. `$a = foo(); echo array_fetch(1, $a);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`array_fetch(1, $a = foo());` is **not**

> assign `$a` and pass `$a` to function.

It **is**

> assign `$a` and pass the result of assign to function.

And result of `assign` operation is the value which is assigned.

So, `array_fetch(1, $a = foo());` is equivalent to `array_fetch(1, ['a', 'b', 'c'])` where second argument is not a variable.

So, the only solution is still:

```
$a = foo();
echo array_fetch(1, $a);
```

Comment: *"Hope downvoter will write his own answer."* - How so true and I've been downvoted for a perfectly good/valid answer/solution before and they ended up posting complete crap or didn't post at all. They should put their money where their mouths are ;-) *Cheers*